# Laravel Return registered ID

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm trying to customize the register of Laravel and I have this working but I need to add in some fields the last ID registered. In my actual code it registers all OK, but no login automatic after register.

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:ssn'],
            'account' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:user_auth'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $ssn1 = mt_rand(1000000,9999999);
        $ssn2 = mt_rand(100000,999999);
        $ssn = $ssn1 . $ssn2;

        $user_auth = User::create([
            'account' => $data['account'],
            'password' => DB::raw("CONVERT(BINARY(16), ".l2off($data['password'])." )"),

            'quiz1' => $data['quiz1'],
            'quiz2' => $data['quiz2'],

            'answer1' => DB::raw("CONVERT(BINARY(16), ".l2off($data['answer1'])." )"),
            'answer2' => DB::raw("CONVERT(BINARY(16), ".l2off($data['answer2'])." )"),
        ]);


        $userId = $user_auth->id;

        $ssn_info = ssn::create([
            'ssn' => $ssn,
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'job' => $data['job'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'zip' => $data['zip'],
            'addr_main' => $data['addr_main'],
            'addr_etc' => $data['addr_etc'],
            'account_num' => $user_auth->id,

        ]);

        $user_info = user_info::create([
            'account' => $data['account'],
            'ssn' => $ssn,
            'kind' => "99",

        ]);

        $user_account = user_account::create([
            'account' => $data['account'],
            'pay_stat' => "1",

        ]);
    }
}
```

but if change it one to

```
    return User::create([
                'account' => $data['account'],
                'password' => DB::raw("CONVERT(BINARY(16), ".l2off($data['password'])." )"),
    
                'quiz1' => $data['quiz1'],
                'quiz2' => $data['quiz2'],
    
                'answer1' => DB::raw("CONVERT(BINARY(16), ".l2off($data['answer1'])." )"),
                'answer2' => DB::raw("CONVERT(BINARY(16), ".l2off($data['answer2'])." )"),
            ]);
```

It register and automatically logs in, but I don't understand the last ID in the follow sequences.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding `return $user_auth;` at the end.